# c programming how to write this in main

Tags: oracle9i

You can write the prototypes without the variable names?

```
int example(examplestruct *var1, examplestruct *var2);
void done(examplestruct *var1,FILE *f);

 struct {
    int* field1;
    int field2;
    }examplestruct;
```

Is it possible to write the prototypes without name variables?

Comment: yes a function prototype doesn't have to have argument names, just types - you can't have nested functions in C though, so no functions defined in main()

Comment: For me it looks perfectly fine! you don't have to write the parameter names in a function prototype! But you can't define a function in a other function

Comment: what does `i could write it in the main and just write where read is the name of the variable?` mean? I'm having trouble parsing that sentence. Same with `remove a function and make it in the main`. What do you mean by "remove a function" and "make a function in main"

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me if this is acceptable in C language? You can write the prototypes without the variable names?

Yes.

As for the second question:

If you want a function to be inside `main()`, then take the body of the function, put it in `main()` and make sure that the arguments that the function had are well handled.

---

This example will clear things up:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int);

void inc_p(int);

int main(void) {

  int num = 5;
  print(num);
  inc_p(num);

  // to get rid of inc_p(), copy paste it's body inside main
  // and you will get this
  //  a++;
  //  print(a);
  // However, a was an argument, here you need to use
  // the variable declared in main(), i.e. 'num'

  num++;
  print(num);

  return 0;
}

void print(int a) {
  printf("%d\n", a);
}

void inc_p(int a) {
  a++;
  print(a);
}
```

Comment: If the asnwer is OK for you, then you may accept it @cstack